# Django - Managing messages strings by one single file

Tags: python, django, message

I'm currently experiencing that my application has become quite large and I'm handling a lot of different messages at my views.py. I have to manually set every message string I return to my user at the specific view.

Now my idea was to manage all potential messages my application returns to the user e.g. an error or a success message by only one single file so that I don't have to set the same message strings three or four times for basically the same thing ...

Example - current state:

```
if example.objects.filter(author=request.user, status='Magic').count() >= config.USER_MAX_MAGIC:
    messages.error(request,
                   'You have reached the maximum amount of Magic.')
    return redirect('magic')
```

Example - Wanted state

```
from app_messages import xyz # These containing the actual string that should get returned to the user

if example.objects.filter(author=request.user, status='Magic').count() >= config.USER_MAX_MAGIC:
    messages.error(request,
                   xyz)
    return redirect('magic')
```

My question now is: What does `xyz` need to look like and is this in general a good idea to accomplish a management of error, success, info etc. messages like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use an `Enum` if you want to do it this way, so `xyz` would look like `ErrorMessages.max_magic.value` (assuming `ErrorMessages` is the `Enum`). But a dictionary would also work.

Comment: xyz just needs to evaluate to a string how you store it within that file is up to you. It could be a dictionary, an object a series of string constants

Comment: You could use *.po files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/